# Class diagram from code first entity classes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, uml, class-diagram

I have POCO classes for code first and I used them to create a class diagram. It automatically added the EF virtual navigation properties to both parts of relationships. Is it right? Should I show EF navigation properties in class diagram or I should customize it?

Thanks.

Comment: I know pogo, but what is POCO?

Comment: POCOS(Plain old CLR objects) are simply entities of Domain [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075245/what-is-poco-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Ah, some Mickeysoft stuff. No wonder I did not know it. Obviously the same goes for CLR... Maybe you should tag it with .NET