# Is Entity Framework 6 used code first approach only?

Tags: entity-framework

Is Entity Framework 6 uses code first approach only ? I am a bit confused when we talk about code first approach, but i want to know if it works only with entity framework 6 or entity framework 6 uses code first approach only?

Answer (score 1):

No, EF 6 does not ony support Code First. Code first can be a confusing name. It does not mean that you write code and then generate a db from that. You could in fact both target a new or an existing database using code first strategy. Code first simply imply not using the model designer (edmx) to create and maintain your db-context in your development project.

Some links to get you going:

[EF 6 Database first (with asp.net mvc)](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database)

[EF 6 Code first against new db (with asp.net mvc)](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

[EF 6 Code first against existing db](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)

Ps. Worth noting is that [EF 7 (Core) will only support the Code First approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx) (but of course, as in EF 6, against a new or an existing db).

Comment: Does Database First uses .edmx files only?

Comment: I have noticed that in Code First Approach there is no .edmx files generated ?

Comment: Yes and Yes, But Code first could be targeted against an existing database (where I thing the naming could be a bit off as it is in fact "database first" and not code first...) But the big point with code first would be that you have Poco classes representing your db/context and with database first you generate the edmx from your database.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this links to find the Different approach of `Entity Framework`,

Basically we have 3 approach in that,

1. **Code-First**

   - [Code First(Reverse Engineering) development targeting an existing
     database.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200620.aspx)
   - [simple-code-first-example](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/simple-code-first-example.aspx)
2. **Model-First**

   - [model-first-with-entity-framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/model-first-with-entity-framework.aspx)
3. **Database-First**

   - [database-first-with-entity-framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/database-first-with-entity-framework.aspx)

Comment: Does Database First uses .edmx files only?

Comment: I have noticed that in Code First Approach there is no .edmx files generated ?

Comment: Yes in Code First the [POCO class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075245/what-is-poco-in-entity-framework)  is generated not .edmx file.