# How/Where asp.net mvc handle decoding and of the action methods parameters

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webclient

I have two ASP.NET MVC web applications deployed under IIS8 (let me call them sender and receiver web applications). I am calling an action method inside the receiver web application from an action method inside sender.

Now inside the sender, I have the following action method that will upload a `string` to an external action method on the receiver:

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())                
{
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resource);      
    string url = "https://receiver/CreateResource?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    wc.Headers.Add("Authorization", token);
    output = wc.UploadString(uri, data)
}
```

I am encoding the `string` using UTF-8 before uploading it, since I will be passing unicode characters such as `£` , `¬` , etc...

On the receiver web application, the receiving action method is as follows:

```
public List<CRUDOutput> CreateResource(Resource resourceinfo)
```

At the beginning I thought my approach would not work well. Since I am sending an encoded data (using `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`) from the sender to the receiver action method, and I am not doing any kind of decoding on the receiver action method.

However, it seems on the receiving action method the `resourceinfo` received the correct decoded values. So it seems like ASP.NET MVC will handle the decoding automatically somewhere.

**First question:**

Can anyone tell me how ASP.NET MVC handles the decoding inside the receiving action method?

**Second question:**

Inside my `WebClient()` method I define the following to specify the content type header:

```
 wc.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Yet, it seems that this does not have any effect in my case. When i remove the above line of code, nothing changes. Can anyone tell me if defining the content type header will have any effect in my case?

**Last question:**

If I do not explicitly define the UTF-8 encoding using `wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;` will `WebClient()` use a default encoding?

Comment: Normally, you do not need to encode data. Look like you post a string to CreateResource action method, but it is expecting a model. What is Resource?

Comment: @Win but if i do not encode using UTF8 then i will not be able to pass non-ASCII characters such as £ or ¬ ,, that why i chose to encode the data to be able to pass non-ASCII characters... other wise if i pass charecter such as £ from sender ,, it will be received as ? inside the receiver action method... for the Resource it is model class which i have created on both the sender and the receiver web applications..beside this i am sending a json string from sender which represents the Resource model class (the json string which is being sent is a serialize representation of the model class)...

Answer (score 4):

#### First: Where/what does the decoding of an Http Request?

In ASP.NET the process of taking an HTTP request and turning it into a C# [POCO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075245/what-is-poco-in-entity-framework) is called [Model Binding](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html).

The [web api pipeline poster](http://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf) provides a very good depiction of when this happens, and what does it.

Here is an excerpt from there to show the area that I think you're looking for: [image: Model Binding Diagram]

If there is a media type formatter (highlighted in red above) that matches the MIME header in the HTTP request, that media type formatter will read the message. As described in the [model binding resources](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters), the media type formatters can be configured via the [HttpConfiguration.Formatters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpconfiguration.formatters(v=vs.118).aspx) property at Application Start, usually in Startup.cs or Global.Asax.cs. I'll bet that if you debug, and inspect Config.Formatters, you'll find a JsonFormatter that is configured for UTF-8.

[The tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) has a code snippet in the section "Adding a Media Formatter to the Web API Pipeline" for setting a custom formatter.

```
public static void ConfigureApis(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.Add(new ProductCsvFormatter()); 
}
```

#### Second: Why doesn't specifying the charset seem to have an effect?

Have you sent any higher level characters that would have made a difference, or tried setting a different charset other than UTF8 for the header? W3Schools has a good table ["Differences Between Charsets"](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp) try using that to test the differences of your charset headers and the resulting decoded values.

I think the real answer to this question, is the answer to your third question...

#### Third: What is the default charset?

I'm pretty sure, but don't have any solid resource for this, that UTF-8 is the de-facto standard these days for encoding/decoding strings. I can't really recall the last time I have seen anything other than UTF-8 except for the last time I programmed in C.

However, in .NET you can check the encoding of WebClient using the [WebClient.Encoding property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx). It says there that: `A Encoding that is used to encode strings. The default value of this property is the encoding returned by Default.` Where 'Default' is: [Encoding.Default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default(v=vs.110).aspx). I definitely won't be surprised if you debug your program and find that to be UTF-8.

A good idea would be to play around with this setting, and use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the resulting headers.

P.S. I feel obligated to mention Joel's [great post on this topic](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).