# How to use ServiceStack Redis API?

Tags: c#, api, redis, servicestack, servicestack.redis

I am new to service stack redis api. So i am getting little confused while using the service stack redis api. I want to know IRedisTypedClient"<"T">"?  
1) What stands for "<"T">"?  
2) What are the parameters we can pass in the "<"T">"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [IRedisTypeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisTypedClient.cs) interface provides a typed version of the Redis Client API where all its API's accept a typed [POCOs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672476/85785) (i.e. Plain Old CSharp Object) for its value body which is in contrast to [IRedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs) which just accepts raw strings. Behind the scenes the Typed API's just serialize the POCO's to a JSON string but it's typed API provides a nicer API to work with when dealing with rich complex types.

The API to create a `IRedisTypeClient<T>` is to use the `IRedisClient.As<T>` API, e.g:

```
public class Todo
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
}

IRedisClient redis = redisManager.GetClient();
var redisTodos = redis.As<Todo>();
```

As seen above you can create a typed API from any user-defined POCO, which now provides API's that lets you work directly native `Todo` types, e.g:

```
var todo = new Todo
{
    Id = redisTodos.GetNextSequence(),
    Content = "Learn Redis",
    Order = 1,
};

redisTodos.Store(todo);

Todo savedTodo = redisTodos.GetById(todo.Id);
savedTodo.Done = true;
redisTodos.Store(savedTodo);

"Updated Todo:".Print();
redisTodos.GetAll().ToList().PrintDump();
```

There's a [stand-alone version of this example](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Redis.Tests/Examples/ServiceStack_Redis_UseCase.cs) as well as a Live Demo of [Backbones TODO app with a Redis backend](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos#todos) which makes use of the RedisClient Typed API.

Comment: I am using the visual studio 2010 .NET Framework 4.0. I have included the servicestack API by NuGet. In this environment still the POCO is serialized as a JSON string or any thing else?

Comment: @Immanuel POCO's are always serialized as JSON behind the scenes, but this is just an impl detail you shouldn't have to worry about.

Comment: Is it in Any platform we use stackservice redis the poco will always serialized as JSON?

Comment: @Immanuel yes, there aren't any differences between platforms.